# Change Add to Cart button in WooCommerce based on item Category

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I am wanting to change the Add to Cart WooCommerce button when in the single item page based on the category of the item.

In my scenario, if it is a 'team-gear' category item I want the Add to Cart button to be replaced with a button that says "Order Request" and has a URL to my order request form. If it is any other category I would like the Add to Cart to remain the same.

I am completely unsure of the code to do this, though I keep reading it may take place in the functions.php file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

simple and direct way:

1) copy the template file simple.php located in woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php into your theme folder under /woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart

2) change the code in simple.php by adding your conditions after make a query like $category = get_queried_object();
$category_ID = $category->term_id;
and the put insert your customized code for your cart